# Routing via browserHistory when using hashHistory doesnt appear to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Not sure if I am doing something incorrectly.

I have uploaded a reduced test case at this location: https://github.com/CervantesVive/test-react-router-hash

It loads a ReactJS view with a div and a Link and both route to '/register'

The div does it via

```
browserHistory.push('/register');
```

The Link is just a react-router link.

If I configure history with `browserHistory` then both work.

If I configure history with `hashHistory` then only the link works.

Any ideas/suggestions on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [react-router 2](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#navigating-in-route-components) you should not use the history object to do the navigation, you should use the router instead.

As Login is a route component, you can get access to the router using the context:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div onClick={ this.onRegister }>Reg Button</div>
                <Link to='/register' >
                    Register Link
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    },
    onRegister() {
        console.log('register button');
        this.context.router.push('/register');
    }
});
```

This will work for hash or browser history.

Comment: What is the context here?